# Как получить список пользователей определенного класса на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Мне нужно реализовать такую штуку. Есть, например, пользователи "Менеджер"ы, нужно получить список менеджеров со стороны пользователя, выбрать пользователю его менеджера и сохранить. Все можно в разделе пользователя сделать, но как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну на счет того что в Вашем понимании значит "пользователи определенного класса", не совсем понятно. Скорее всего Вы имели ввиду пользовательскую роль. Если так, то можете использовать [get_users()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_users). Из вопроса не совсем ясно где конкретно это нужно реализовать (где происодит этот выбор пользователю менеджера и кем).

Comment: Да, вы правы, роли пользователей. Все нужно реализовать через function.php грубо говоря. Смотрите, что в итоге должно получиться.Есть пользователи с ролью Менеджер. Пользователь создается в ручную, пока что, потом через битрикс, ну то потом. Вот, создаем пользователя в ручную и в его профиле администратор определяет ему конкретного менеджера, т.е. в настройках пользователя должен быть селект с выбором пользователей с ролью менеджер. Сохраняем и к пользователю привязан менеджер, потом я хочу на фронте отображать информацию и чат с конкретным менеджером, который к нему привязан.